# Mark sharp does nothing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I understand this is a very basic question, but I cannot find the solution. Google & other Stack Exchange gave me no solution either.

I am following Blender Game Asset Creation guide from Blender Cloud, at some point Aidy selects his whole model and does **Shade Smooth**. Then he selects some edges and **marks** them **sharp**.

In Aidy his tutorial you can clearly see the difference between marking sharp and not. As seen here (this is taken from his tutorial)

[image]

When I do this in my Blender File, I see no difference. I've tried removing any doubles, but I can not think of anything else. What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Did you add Edge Split modifier / checked *Autosmooth* option ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As MrZak said,  Make sure Auto Smooth is turned on, (for manual edge split, the angle should be 180) ... For Auto edge split (Ie: blender decides where to split the edges) I find that an angle of 60 to 80 degrees works mostly, although it depends on the mesh :) 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, and MrZak. It seems Aidy did indeed mark that checkbox, but I failed to see it. I can now continue with the tutorial!