# Mark Sharp doesn't work as I expected

Tags: edges

I am trying to model a wall. There will be some curves in the model, so I will need to apply Sub Surf modifier while keeping the corner edges sharp. Please find my model here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/tz4cmab53uleb16/1.blend/file

This is what my work looks like before the sub surf modifier:

[image]

This what it looks like even when I have marked the sharp edges:

[image]

I had expected it to keep the right angles and prevent them from bending. Was I wrong?
I have also enabled Auto Smooth.

Please note that I have already seen this thread:

[Mark sharp does nothing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57387/mark-sharp-does-nothing)

Thank you!!!

Comment: Mark sharp is only used for Shade smooth and auto smooth, Subsurface modifier does not work like you think with mark sharp, what you need there is Edge Crease (Shift + E)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand, *Mark Sharp* will affect the shading only in order to make the edge shading look sharp, but it won't change the shape of the edge itself, so it will stay round if you've assigned a *Subdivision Surface* to your object, see the difference:

[image]

What you're looking for may be the *Edge Crease* option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> or in the *N panel > Item > Edge Data > Crease*):

[image]

There's also the *Bevel* modifier and you can play with the *Edge Bevel Weight* of your edge (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> or in the *N panel > Item > Edge Data > Bevel Weight*, and in the modifier choose *Limit Method > Weight*) to determine if it will be affected by the modifier:

[image]

Or simply bevel for real:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! and thank you too, @Emir!